# Car travel through France to Spain - what restrictions are in place due to Covid19?

Tags: transit, france, spain, borders, covid-19

I have a villa in Spain that I was planning to go to at the end of July. I know that all borders were at one time closed - but I am also now told that they are open? but, in Spain, you need a green residency permit or you may be stopped? What is the true situation, please?

Comment: Nobody knows what the situations will be next month, much less at the end of July. Though it is quite likely you should forget about any plans involving long distance travel or crossing any borders. At the present time, you will NOT be allowed to enter France or travel through it. What will happen in July is the trillion-euro question.

Comment: @jcaron That is not accurate at all. I have just travelled from the UK to the Czech Republic via a combination of plane and car. The important thing is your *reason* for travelling, and the specific [list of reasons that are allowed *per country*](https://oecd.github.io/OECD-covid-action-map/) that you need to pass through. I had my documentation checked very carefully at each border, but was able to pass freely as my reason was on the list of essential ones.

Comment: @JBentley I was commenting in the context of "going to my villa in Spain", which is definitely not a valid reason for traveling through France at this time, though I should have made that clearer. But indeed, with the right justification, you can still travel. And things may change completely by the end of July.

Comment: @jcaron Agreed, but we don't know OP's reason for going to his villa - I think everyone is assuming it is for a holiday, but OP hasn't said that. My travel was to go to my second residence in Prague, and it was allowed because of the reason I had to travel there (family/work related reasons).

Comment: _"I have a villa in Spain that I was planning to go to at the end of July."_ Please don't. Remain at home. Forget about [recreational] foreign travel this year.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think it's too early to argue if that is good advice. Things may improve later in the year, and while recreational foreign travel is certainly not essential, it should be encouraged as soon as it is safe, tourism will be essential to avert a major depression in many European countries.

Comment: @Crazymoomin tourism will not be safe until there is a cure, vaccine, highly effective treatments, or widespread immunity.  It is highly unlikely for any of that to happen this year.  The most likely thing to happen this year is a second wave.

Comment: @eps That's not likely to happen until mid 2021 at the earliest. Most countries simply can't hold on that long. I think it's more likely that countries will open up once new cases drop low enough, with some added precautions.

Comment: @eps heavy PPE use and lots of testing could also make it relatively safe, especially if people are able to quarantine after traveling. It's likely we won't have the things you mentioned for years, and it's unlikely the current lockdowns will or can go on for that long. No one can know what the advice from experts will be in the coming months, so let's not speculate.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you are living in Spain or a Spanish national, borders are closed at present (10 May 2020).  As JCaron pointed out, nobody knows whether it will be worse or better in July.  But for today:

These are the people who are exempt from border restrictions:

> ## Air, land and sea borders
>
> Only Spanish citizens or those who can prove residency in Spain by presenting a green residency certificate, are allowed to enter Spain through airports, ports or land borders.
>
> **The following categories of people are also exempt from border restrictions:**
>
> - Frontier workers
> - Health workers
> - Those who are transiting Spain to their country of residence in EU/Schengen area
> - Those with a Schengen visa who are transiting Spain to their country of residence in EU/Schengen area
> - Those who can prove that they need to enter Spain for essential reasons

([Source](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/coronavirus))

The Coronavirus is still a health crisis and would highly not recommend travelling even if you live there as you have another residence in France I assume. That is then not essential but recreational travel.

Comment: Even **within** most countries at present, moving between different residences is not considered essential.

Comment: I'm living in Spain. Most regions have a 1 km from home restriction (1 hour max per day for sport or walking). All regions have restricted movement beetween regions. So, in case you can cross the border, you'll have to go directly to your residence and stay there for weeks. And more, some regions like Madrid have still a lot of active covid cases. Believe me, you don't want to travel to Spain now.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding France, while you may technically be able to enter the country (if you are an EU/EEA citizen or resident), you are not allowed to travel inside the country except for specific listed purposes (professional travel, funeral…) Going on holiday or switching residences is not allowed.

The rules are set to change tomorrow (May 11) and short trips inside the country will be allowed again. I haven't been able to find the new forms but similar restrictions should however still apply to travel longer than 100 km.

The French government hasn't announced when these new restrictions could be lifted. [The official stance is that this would be evaluated at the end of May.](https://www.gouvernement.fr/sites/default/files/cimages/infographie_deconfinement.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have told, in the current situation the rules will change as a result of the spread and control of Covid. The more controlled it is, the more lenient you can expect the rules to become.

I will just explain the current status in Spain so you can make your own evaluation.

As of now, travel between Spanish provinces is restricted to essential travel. Moving to a second residence **is not** essential travel.

Spain is currently implementing a plan to de-escalate restrictions, in which regions (often provinces, but not always) where the disease seems to be under control with be allowed more lenient rules.

Today a significant part of Spain will get into "phase 1", the rest will remain at "phase 0". At "phase 1" there are reduced movility restrictions **within your zone** (you can move to a secondary residence in the same zone in phase 1, but not in phase 0) but movement between zones is still restricted to essential travel.

Each two weeks conditions will be evaluated and it may be decided that a zone advances to the next phase, remains at the current one or even returns to a previous phase. There are a total of 4 phases.

Given that Spain's economy depends a great deal on tourism, if conditions allow for most of the country to reach phase 4 it is to be expected that the entry of foreign visitors will be eased.

Yet it remains to be seen if phase 4 is reached, and which conditions would apply on entry (e.g. maybe they will require visitors to self-isolate for a time after entering the country, or visitors will be rejected if they fail a medical test). Or it is even entirely possible that by the end of July this de-escalation schema has already been changed to something else.